# In Rust, which iterator method is preferred when wanting a non-mutable reference?

Tags: vector, iterator, rust

I have the following code:

```
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    for i in &v {
        println!("A reference to {}", i);
    }
    for i in v.iter(){
        println!("A ?? to {}", i);
    }
}
```

I am trying to understand what the difference is between the first for/in loop vs the second for/in loop.  Is the second one equivalent to the first one and if so, which is the preferred more idiomatic choice?

I have been reading contradictory information on this because I think some articles refer to older versions of Rust so I'm getting a bit confused.

Comment: Thank you, I edited the post...and your link does actually clarify my question.  This can be closed.

Comment: I like that you used the same example data as the other question (`vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`) ^_^.

Comment: Haha, yep, I also like that you actually answered the link you posted.  Thx again.